# Temp table causing full scan on table unlike Table Variable in a left outer join queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, table-valued-parameters, table-variable

If I switch out the `@GameIds table variable` with the `#GameIds temp table` in the bottom query I get a full table scan on some tables, making a longer execution time, and large memory grant warning.  I thought a temp table would give a better execution plan because it has statistics on it compared to a table variable.  The table variable does a nice join between tables with a clustered index seek.  Am I missing something with the temp table?

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Test].[GetGameParticipants]
    @GameIds [Test].[BulkIdType] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        
        CREATE TABLE #GameIds
        (
          Id INT
        )
        CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_GameIds_Temp ON #GameIds (Id);
        INSERT INTO #GameIds
        SELECT Id FROM @GameIds
```

**Select Statement**

```
SELECT
                ...
            FROM 
                    Test.DivisionGameTeamResult divisionGameTeamResult LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    
                    Test.DivisionBracketParticipant divisionBracketParticipant ON divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionGameTeamResultId = divisionGameTeamResult.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.DivisionBracketParticipantPart divisionBracketParticipantPart ON divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.DivisionBracketParticipantPartId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.DivisionBracketPart divisionBracketPart ON divisionBracketPart.Id = divisionBracketParticipantPart.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.DivisionBracket divisionBracket ON divisionBracket.Id = divisionBracketPart.DivisionBracketId LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    Test.DivisionBracketParticipantTeam divisionBracketParticipantTeam ON divisionBracketParticipantTeam.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.DivisionTeam divisionTeamBracket ON divisionTeamBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantTeam.DivisionTeamId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.Team teamBracket ON teamBracket.Id = divisionTeamBracket.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    
                    Test.DivisionBracketParticipantBracket divisionBracketParticipantBracket ON divisionBracketParticipantBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN

                    Test.DivisionBracketParticipantPool divisionBracketParticipantPool ON divisionBracketParticipantPool.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.DivisionPool divisionPoolBracket ON divisionPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantPool.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.Division poolDivision ON divisionPoolBracket.DivisionId = poolDivision.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    
                    Test.DivisionBracketParticipantTeamPool divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool ON divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool.Id = divisionBracketParticipant.Id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.DivisionTeamPool divisionTeamPoolBracket ON divisionTeamPoolBracket.Id = divisionBracketParticipantTeamPool.DivisionTeamPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.DivisionPool divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket ON divisionTeamPoolPoolBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionPoolId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.DivisionTeam divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket ON divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolBracket.DivisionTeamId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    Test.Team teamPoolTeamBracket ON teamPoolTeamBracket.Id = divisionTeamPoolTeamBracket.Id
            WHERE 
                EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @GameIds WHERE Id = divisionGameTeamResult.GameId)
```

[image]

Comment: Why a non-clustered index? Why not create a clustered index and set the column as the primary key of the temp table?

Comment: It's the same deal, doesnt matter, full scan

Comment: You've got a lot of rows in that table, meaning the selectivity isn't very high. This is likely why the optimizer decides a full scan and a merge join is a better bet than individual seeks. Of course, as always, the optimizer can be wrong. A table variable without statistics (note that you can force statistics to be considered, with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`) will by default be estimated to have 1 (one) row in it (prior to SQL Server 2019), giving different estimates. Sometimes the "wrong" estimate is the "right" one as far as plan decisions go.

Comment: This particular query is a challenge for the optimizer due to the very high number of joins, all of which are `LEFT OUTER`, meaning there's great potential for a single incorrect estimate to throw off row counts. There's not really any easy remedy against this other than to make sure your statistics are up to snuff in all the tables, and even then you may not get the best possible plan. A slightly less normalized design and/or indexed views to represent tables joined multiple times more effectively and/or breaking up the query in stages can also help.

Comment: Maybe try creating the index after inserting the data, and make it clustered and if possible unique.

Comment: If you leave 1 row in the temp table highly likely you will get a plan like for the table variable. It doesn't matter how many rows you have stored in a table variable Sql Server creates a query plan based on the estimation of the 1 row (or 100 rows in Sql Server 2019) in a table variable.

Comment: @AntonGrig that's true for SQL Server until v15

Comment: I am on 2016 which looks to be v13

Comment: In which case you're doing the right thing to prefer tables over table variables.

Comment: Is [id] unique in #GameIds? If so why don't use inner join with #GameIds. It would be better for the optimizer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `RECOMPILE` only helps table variables for cardinality, not statistics.

Comment: Consider removing unnecessary joins, changing to `inner` joins, maybe indexed views. Side note: table aliases make queries much more readable